# SQL - How to avoid some records after a Group By

Tags: sql, group-by, having

After an inner join and a group by, i have the following output:

```
Make, Model
Ferrari, A
Ferrari, B
Aston, A
Opel, A
```

My question is.. How to ignore the records with make `Ferrari` from the output of the query because it contains more than one model in the second table (models)?

PS: The second table may contains more than one record, even for the same model.

**I don't want to ignore only Ferraris. I want to ignore all makes under the same situation (with more than 1 model in table two).**

Current query:

```
select c.Make, m.Model
from cars as c
inner join models as m on c.make = m.make
where c.year = '2017'
group by c.Make, m.Model
```

Comment: what is the name of your example table? `cars` or `models` ?

Comment: @SqlZim, i want to show just the table of makes.

Comment: @JohnParam No, i mean you start your question with a table, and say what you want to do with that table, but you don't tell us which table that is in your query.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense and thus have deleted my answer. With what you saying then @SqlZim answer should be what you want but if it's still doesn't answer then you have to dig more and give better explanation and more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `not exists()`

```
select c.Make, m.Model
from cars as c
  inner join models as m 
    on c.make = m.make
where c.year = '2017'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from cars as i
    where i.Make = c.Make
      and i.Model <> c.Model)
)
group by c.Make, m.Model
```

You could use `having` with `count(distinct c.Model))=1` to only return those with a single model.

```
select c.Make, m.Model
from cars as c
  inner join models as m 
    on c.make = m.make
where c.year = '2017'
group by c.Make, m.Model
having count(distinct c.Model)=1
```

Comment: Having is not working as expected. I got the same output with `having count(distinct c.Model)=1`.

Comment: @JohnParam Added an alternative that uses `where not exists()` to remove those `make` that have more than one `model`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ...

```
select c.Make, m.Model
from cars as c
inner join models as m on c.make = m.make
where c.year = '2017' and c.make != 'Ferrari'
group by c.Make, m.Model
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform some kind of aggregation to count the number of models for each make.  If you're using a DBMS that supports window functions, then you could use them to do the job:

```
select c.make, m.model
from cars as c
  inner join (
    select make, model, count(*) over (partition by make) as model_count
    from model
  ) m
    on c.make = m.make
where c.year = '2017' and m.model_count = 1
```

You no longer need to make it an aggregate query (by using a `GROUP BY` clause) as long as (`c.make`, `c.year`) can be relied upon to be unique, for the filter conditions will then ensure that no make appears more than once.  For correctness, however, that does rely on (`model.make`, `model.model`) being unique.

NOTE: I have supposed that you're performing the join you really want to perform. Since you've not provided the table structures, I have nothing else to go by.  However, I'm suspicious that this may not be the join you really do want to perform.  In particular, I'm wondering whether you really want information about which makes produced only a single model *in the specified year*, and if so, then it looks like you need deeper changes to achieve that.